# Service Calendar Bulk Time off

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

We have a bunch of Facility/Equipment that need to be blocked out on holidays so that nobody including website users can book on them on specific dates.

Whats the best way of doing this rather than doing each one individually through work hours?

Answer (score 0):

I've never done it before, but this should get you closer: write a program that creates calendars of Type 2 (Holiday Schedule) and associates them to the appropriate calendar.  [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn689038.aspx)'s a brief description, and [here](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/179022)'s some related sample code.